# How to hide or close sending progress dialog after sharing video with ShareDialog on facebook with facebook sdk

Tags: android, video, sharing, facebook-sdk-4.x

i am using 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)' to share video from my android to Facebook it is posting successfully but after sharing the video,i am getting translucent screen with sending progress dialog,even after video has posted on facebook progress dialog box is still showing and some time it show for very long time,please see the screenshot I don't want to show that translucent screen after sharing video, how i can achieve that.[image].

Comment: maybe smth like dialog.dismiss() will help you?

Comment: this is not a custom dialog this activity/screen is from facebook sdk i don't know how it is getting trigger so not able to handle it.

Comment: can you show the code of your dialog?

Comment: Uri videoFileUri = data.getData();
            ShareVideo video = new ShareVideo.Builder()
                    .setLocalUrl(videoFileUri)
                    .build();
            ShareVideoContent content = new ShareVideoContent.Builder()
                    .setVideo(video)
                    .build();

            shareDialog.show(content, ShareDialog.Mode.AUTOMATIC);

Comment: Please *update* your question with the (formatted) code instead of adding as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add smth like `shareDialog.dismiss()` when your process will be finished. I hope that it will help you.

Comment: there is no method like shareDialog.dismiss() in shareDialog, i dont thik it is about sharedialog,it is the activity which is getting trigger after sharing content on facebook, and that activity i am not able to find out

Comment: maybe smth like shareDialog.cancel()? I think this dialog can be dismissed via its abilities.

Comment: there is only  shareDialog.show()  and    shareDialog.canShow() methods are present

Comment: the strangest way to solve your problem is activity recreation)) but I think that this dialog has some methods for dismissing, anyway I hope it has)